# How to connect to jmx with groovy faster

Tags: groovy, jmx

I use weblogic example: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+and+JMX to connect jmx with groovy

Problem is that connection takes too long:

```
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    println System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
    def server = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceURL, h).MBeanServerConnection
    println System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
```

I have about 200 groovy script. Every script is doing something else but all need to connect to jmx. When I want to execute all it take about hour and more. Is there some options how to do it faster ?

Comment: Can't you connect once, then share this connection amongst them?

Comment: that is options but I dont know how I can do it. Every script should works alone too

Comment: @tim_yates any idea how to share connection between scripts ?

Comment: How are you calling the scripts?

Comment: groovy DoSomething.groovy -F request.xml (and other parameters)

Comment: So you're just typing that for all 200 of your scripts?

Comment: if I want to execute 200 scripts  I have some bash scripts which execute this groovy: doSomething() {  
     DoSomething.groovy -F request.xml )

Comment: `doSomething() { DoSomething.groovy -F request.xml )` doesn't make sense...  Is this the bash script or the groovy script? Can you put your _exact_ use case (with maybe an example) into the question?  It's hard to come up with a solution that fits your situation if we don't know your situation

Comment: oh yea sorry that was wrong. I have saved 200 commands in file and when I want to execute it I copy it to terminal so answer for your question is yes but instead of typing I copy this commands

Comment: You are the one that wants help it is your responsibility to write your question clearly

Comment: and where is the problem ?

Comment: @tim_yates so any idea how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so the answer is very simpler. I need to use this project: http://kobo.github.io/groovyserv/

then I just created class `JmxSharedConection` with static method where I add connection and now it works much faster

Answer (score 1):

I would take tim's suggestion and implement a shared connection as a [synchronized] singleton. So in effect, you establish  the connection once and then each script uses it as needed. For some extra pizass, register a [connection listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/remote/JMXConnector.html#addConnectionNotificationListener%28javax.management.NotificationListener,%20javax.management.NotificationFilter,%20java.lang.Object%29) to your [JMXConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/remote/JMXConnector.html), and when connectivity is lost, start a reconnect loop, throwing exceptions to the calling scripts until you reconnect.

Comment: and can you show me some example ? I have no idea how to start